# Add Protocol for MediaWiki Links Besides HTTP

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

Is there a way to add protocols to linking for MediaWiki?

For example:

- Works: [http://www.google.com Google]
- Doesn't work: [ftp://www.someplace.com Some FTP place]
- Doesn't work: [conisio://something?something=awesome Something Awesome]

In the above example, I want to add **ftp** and **conisio** protocols

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUrlProtocols](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgUrlProtocols)

Add to $wgUrlProtocols 1.6 and above

For older versions, need to add a line in the function replaceExternalLinks in ./includes/Parser.php